# Conditionally pass params to a script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script running on Linux that accepts some parameters.
I would like to do something like:

```
if [[ $CONDITION == "true" ]]; then  
  script param1 --param2  
else
  script param1  
fi
```

I would like to avoid the forking path of the if.
Is there a more optimal way to pass the second parameter?

Comment: Where is this `if`? In the script itself? In another script that calls the target script? Are these options (`--param2`) or arguments (`param1`)? Please [edit] your question and give us more details.

Comment: One other note: `true` is a shell builtin that returns a success exit status. If you use `CONDITION=false` when CONDITION is not true, then you could write: `if "$CONDITION"; then echo yes; fi` or `"$CONDITION" && echo yes`

Comment: @glennjackman:The `true` is not the same as `"true"` right?

Comment: They are the same: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal -- you can execute the command `"echo" "foo"` with no difficulty because the shell will remove the quotes before executing the command.

Comment: For example I often do `valid=false` `if someCondition; then valid=true; fi;` `if ! $valid; then echo Invalid; exit 1; fi`

Comment: @glennjackman:Sorry I didn't understand. Is my condition always going to be true because of using the `true`? I just need a boolean indicator

Comment: `true` and `false` are commands built into the shell. Their only purpose is to return a success or failure exit status. So `if $valid; then echo true; else echo false; fi` where "valid" holds either "true" or "false" will execute the expected branch of the if statement. Therefore, the example I showed **is** a boolean indicator.

Comment: @glennjackman: But when I test the if statement in my post it works. I mean my understanding is that it compares with the string "true"

Comment: Oh, I missed your point. Yes, your code is fine. I was just pointing out the true and false commands could be used.

Answer (score 57):

The most expansible and robust way would probably be to use an array to hold the optional parameter(s):

```
params=()
if [[ $CONDITION == true ]]; then
    params+=(--param2)
fi
script param1 "${params[@]}"
```

Or in shorthand:

```
[[ $CONDITION == true ]] && params+=(--param2)
script param1 "${params[@]}"
```

That avoids repeating the constant part of the command and you can put more than one argument in the array, even the whole command.

Note that it's important to do this with an array: if you replace the array with a regular variable (`params="--param2"; script param1 $params`) you'll either have to expand the variable unquoted, with all the problems that brings, or expand it quoted, in which case you'll pass an empty string as argument if the variable is empty.

In a simple case like this, the "alternate value" expansion can also be used:

```
cond=x
p2="--param2"
script param1 ${cond:+"$p2"}
```

Here, if `cond` is nonempty (regardless of if it's `cond=false` or `cond=0` instead of `cond=true`), the value of `p2` is expanded. This may be seen as less ugly than arrays, but be careful with the placement of the quotes.

See also:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)
- [Using shell variables for command options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/459367/170373)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Comment: it should be noted that this is passing in part the literal string `--`, and not the unary `--` operator

Comment: @StevenPenny, well, the whole idea of a `--` operator only exists in the shell within arithmetic expansions, and there aren't any here. I can't think of any special meaning for the dash in the shell outside of them, either.

Comment: @ilkkachu how can you do this in one line? script param1 ${[[ $CONDITION == true ]] && params+=(--param2)} ?

Comment: @Turnipdabeets, do you mean something like this? `par="x y"; printf ":%s\n" a b  ${par+"$par"}` It should expand `par` as another argument after `b`, if `par` is set (i.e. `unset par; printf ":%s\n" a b  ${par+"$par"}` there would not be an empty argument after `b`). Or you could have `${cond:+"$par"}` to expand `par` if `cond` is non-empty.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with `set -o nounset` when the params variable is empty ? I'm getting "unbound variable" errors. EDIT : use `"${params[@]-}"` with a dash at the end prevents the problem

Answer (score 9):

A versatile way to do this is to set the arguments in an array. The most basic array is the list of positional parameters defined with `set`. You can build the list of parameters in sequence.

```
set -- param1
if [[ $CONDITION == "true" ]]; then  
    set -- "$@" --param2  
fi 

command "$@"
```

Which could be reduced to:

```
set -- param1
[[ $CONDITION == "true" ]] && set -- "$@" --param2
command "$@"
```

If the list of positional parameters needs to be preserved, then either:

- Use a function:

  ```
  callcommand(){     set -- param1
                     [[ $CONDITION == "true" ]] && set -- "$@" --param2
                     command "$@"       
               }
  callcommand
  ```
- Or use some other array variable:

  ```
  paramArray=()
  paramArray+=(param1)
  [[ $CONDITION == "true" ]] && paramArray+=( "--param2" )
  command "${paramArray[@]}"
  ```

Comment: I don't really understand this. `param1` is already a parameter. Does this change the parameter array of the script?

Comment: @Jim No, `param1` is not an argument of the script code above, it become a parameter of the `command` called. Yes, the positional parameters are changed (as they are used). See some alternatives in the edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
PARAMS+=" param1"
if [[ $CONDITION == "true" ]]; then  
  PARAMS+=" --param2"
fi
script ${PARAMS}
```

Comment: This would unfortunately not work if any parameter contains spaces and needs to be quoted.

Comment: Further reading: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)