# Bash function with dry-run and exec options

Tags: shell-script, rsync, options

Am writing a bash function to run `rsync`, with possibility of using `--dry-run` option and `--exec` option.  Need some criticism improvements and additional checks.

Might not make much sense for the user to specify both `--dry-run` and `--exec`.  I would simply use --dry-run anyway.

Have started with the following setup.

Calling the following

```
filetr-archive -n -s bkscan -d temp
```

runs the command

```
rsync -av --progress --dry-run --log-file=temp/bkscan.log bkscan temp
```

which makes the file `temp/bkscan.log` whose contents are

```
2021/07/19 23:55:15 [19947] building file list
2021/07/19 23:55:15 [19947] cd+++++++++ bkscan/
2021/07/19 23:55:15 [19947] sent 273 bytes  received 56 bytes  658.00 bytes/sec
2021/07/19 23:55:15 [19947] total size is 108,837,826  speedup is 330,814.06 (DRY RUN)
```

But, `rsync` also produces the following, which never gets saved.  Is the output from `rsync` displayed on the terminal useful?  I could also store the information.  But I wonder how I could do it.

```
  bkscan temp
sending incremental file list
bkscan/
bkscan/BkScan.aux
bkscan/BkScan.cp
bkscan/BkScan.fn
bkscan/BkScan.ky
bkscan/BkScan.log
bkscan/BkScan.pdf
bkscan/BkScan.pg
bkscan/BkScan.texi
bkscan/BkScan.texi~
bkscan/BkScan.tp
bkscan/BkScan.vr
bkscan/BookScan.texi~

sent 273 bytes  received 56 bytes  658.00 bytes/sec
total size is 108,837,826  speedup is 330,814.06 (DRY RUN)
```

---

```
filetr-archive ()
{
  # Process command line options
  shortopts="nel:s:d:"
  longopts="dry-run,exec,log:,source:,destin:"
  opts=$(getopt -o "$shortopts" -l "$longopts"  \
        -n "$(basename $0)" -- "$@")
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "set -- ${opts}"
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
      case "$1" in
      -n|--dry-run)
        shift 1
        local -r dryrun=1
        ;;
      -e|--exec)
        shift 1
        local -r exec=1
        ;;
      -l|--log)
        local logfl=$2
        shift 2
        ;;
      -s|--source)
        local source=$2
        shift 2
        ;;
      -d|--destin)
        local destin=$2
        shift 2
        ;;
      --)
        shift;  break  ;;
      esac
    done
  else
    shorthelp=1 # getopt returned (and reported) an error.
  fi

  if (( filetr_dryrun == 1 )); then 

    echo "rsync -av --progress --log-file=$logfl --dry-run"
    echo "  $source $destin"
    rsync -av --progress --log-file=$logfl --dry-run $source $destin

  elif (( filetr_exec == 1 )); then
      
    # use rsync archive option -a (equivalent to -rlptgoD)
    echo "rsync -av --progress --log-file=$logfl $source $destin"
    # rsync -av --progress --log-file=$logfl $source $destin

  else

    echo "rsync -av --progress --log-file=$logfl $source $destin"
      
  fi
```

Comment: I don't see a question here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is asking for [codereview.se].

Comment: What's wrong with code review?

Comment: From the help file: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Also to avoid: "there is no actual problem to be solved". If you have no problem, don't ask a question.

Comment: If you have a _specific_ issue with your script, then you could ask, but we'd need far more detail and context that a simple dump of the code and a request for improvements. You probably want to ask on [codereview.se] instead, as muru suggested.

Comment: So I would do that. Did not know about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -av --progress --log-file=$logfl --dry-run $source $destin
```

This *needs* double-quotes, i.e. `--log-file="$logfl" --dry-run "$source" "$destin"`. See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373) and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

```
local logfl=$2
```

This probably should also use double-quotes. A plain assignment (`logfl=$2` without the `local` or anything else) is one of the cases that doesn't require them, but with `local`, `export`, `readonly` etc. it's not that clear cut. Just put the quotes there to prevent any issues.

```
  if (( filetr_dryrun == 1 )); then 
    ...
    rsync -av --progress --log-file=$logfl --dry-run $source $destin
  elif (( filetr_exec == 1 )); then
    ...
    rsync -av --progress --log-file=$logfl $source $destin
```

You're duplicating code here, all those `-av`, `--progress`, `$source`, `$destin` are the same in both branches. It's best to avoid that, and since you're running Bash, you can collect the arguments to an array, see: [Conditionally pass params to a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446847/170373)

```
filetr-archive ()
```

The dash works as part of a function name in Bash and in Zsh, but not in Ksh or Dash, so it might make sense to use an underline instead for portability. Of course, you're using non-POSIX stuff like `(( .. ))` anyway, so you might want to consciously ignore at least Dash anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ilkkachu