# passing exclude and include file type extensions to grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have two variables, passed as command line arguments to a bash function, containing exclude and include information on file type extension, using comma as delimiter.

```
excl="el"
excl="el,htm"
incl="texi,org"
```

I want to use `excl` and `incl` to parse the exclude and include options for `grep`.

```
excl="el,htm"
incl="texi,org"
grep -hir --exclude=\*.{el,htm} --include=\*.{org,texi} "$@"

excl="el"
incl="texi,org"
grep -hir --exclude=\*.el --include=\*.{org,texi} "$@"
```

Comment: You can pass what you want to exclude and include by specifying in `excl` and `incl`. To reflect `excl="el,htm"` we would then want to have `--exclude=\*.{el,htm}`.

Comment: Specifying both include and exclude doesn't make sense here, as it appears both are being to limited to filename "extensions" by prepending `*.` (e.g. a filename excluded by matching `*.el` would never be included by matching `*.org`).

Comment: I can see your reasoning that it has to be one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to use arrays to keep track of strings that are separate.  Using a single string to hold multiple values makes it impossible to use the code with suffixes that have the delimiter embedded  (for example the suffix `,v`, which CVS and RCS files have).

```bsh
exclude=( .el .htm )
include=( .texi .org )

opts=( -h -i -r )

for ext in "${exclude[@]}"; do
    opts+=( --exclude="*$ext" )
done
for ext in "${include[@]}"; do
    opts+=( --include="*$ext" )
done

grep "${opts[@]}" "$@"
```

This stores your filename suffixes in two arrays, `exclude` and `include`.  It then iterates over the elements of both arrays, adding the appropriate options to a third array called `opts`.  This third array is then used in the call to `grep`.

The double quoting used when expanding an array, as in e.g. `"${opts[@]}"`, ensures that each individual array element is double quoted and not further split or globbed by the shell.

---

As a function that takes the lists of included and excluded filename suffixes as two separate arguments:

```bsh
call_grep () {
    local -n include="$1"
    local -n exclude="$2"

    shift 2

    local opts=( -h -i -r )
    local ext

    for ext in "${exclude[@]}"; do
        opts+=( --exclude="*$ext" )
    done
    for ext in "${include[@]}"; do
        opts+=( --include="*$ext" )
    done
    
    grep "${opts[@]}" "$@"
}
```

The main part of the script:

```bsh
excl=( .el .htm )
incl=( .texi .org )

call_grep incl excl more arguments here
```

This sets up the function `call_grep` to take the names of two arrays.  The first array is the array of filename suffixes to include and the second one is the array of suffixes to exclude.  The function receives the names of these arrays and uses them to set up two local name-reference variables.
The third argument onwards are passed to `grep` as is.

---

Again, but using real command line parsing in `call_grep`:

```bsh
call_grep () {
        OPTIND=1

        local ext opt
        local opts=( -h -i -r )

        while getopts 'i:e:' opt; do
                case $opt in
                        i)
                                local -n include="$OPTARG"
                                for ext in "${include[@]}"; do
                                        opts+=( --include="*$ext" )
                                done
                                ;;
                        e)
                                local -n exclude="$OPTARG"
                                for ext in "${exclude[@]}"; do
                                        opts+=( --exclude="*$ext" )
                                done
                                ;;
                        *)
                                echo 'Error in option parsing' >&2
                                exit 1
                esac
        done

        shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

        grep "${opts[@]}" "$@"
}
```

The function now takes a `-i` and a `-e` argument (both are optional).  The option argument to each should be the name of an array containing filename suffixes to include or exclude.

You would use this as

```bsh
excl=( .el .htm )
incl=( .texi .org )

call_grep -i incl -e excl -- more arguments here
```

You would need to use `--` to delimit the function's arguments from those that should be passed directly to `grep`.

---

If all you want is a simplified way of calling `grep`, which does not mention shell patterns or long options:

```bsh
call_grep () {
        OPTIND=1

        while getopts 'i:e:' opt; do
                case $opt in
                        i)      opts+=( --include="*$OPTARG" ) ;;
                        e)      opts+=( --exclude="*$OPTARG" ) ;;
                        *)      echo 'error' >&2; exit 1
                esac
        done

        shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

        grep "${opts[@]}" "$@"
}
```

You'd use `-i suffix` repeatedly to include multiple suffixes, and similarly for excluding suffixes.  For example,

```bsh
call_grep -i .texi -e .el -e .htm -i .org -- other arguments for grep here
```

or

```bsh
call_grep -i{.texi,.org} -e{.htm,.el} -- more here for grep
```

Comment: Consider adding a `--` after opts and before $@?

Comment: Using array is fair enough.  But `encl` and `excl` are being passed from `bash` function arguments.

Comment: @JeffSchaller What if `$@` contains further options?

Comment: @Pietru Uh? You might want to update your question, because it does not mention anything about that.

Comment: @Pietru Could the array be built when parsing the arguments? Your function would then require multiple options to be given for multiple suffixes.

Comment: @rowboat User just puts them together in `excl` and `incl` option.  I count then build arrays after reading the comma delimited strings.  `myfunc --incl="texi,org"`.  Had not thought about CVS and RCS files, but we can try to support that as well.  I would need some ideas for that though.

Comment: Perhaps the `incl` and `excl` could use \ as form of escape instruction `--incl=texi,org,\,v`.

Comment: @Pietru And how would you specify a filename suffix that contained ``\``?

Comment: Do you have experience with filename suffixes with  \ ?  What would you suggest filename suffixes to allow ?

Comment: @Pietru Why would you want to disqualify them?  Or, putting it in other words, why would you want to implement a buggy function that can't handle certain filenames when it's fairly easy to implement one that can handle any type of filename?

Comment: Am not disqualifying the possibilities, but my original intention was not so demanding on expectation you have put forward. I could do that for users if we figure an acceptable way to do it.

Comment: @Pietru The other way to solve this is to make the user actually type in `--include="*"{.text,.org}` or `--include='*.texi' --include='*.org'`.  Or even better, teach them how to use `grep` directly.

Comment: Naturally they could use grep directly, but I am also trying to default some parameters so they can adapt it for what they search most.  I suggest an `incl` list with the various possibilities together. What would you have in mind?  I can try both ways if you like.  How can we construct `--incl` to have `,v` etc.

Comment: @Pietru You could do that with `alias grep='grep -hir'` or `alias grep='grep -hir --include="*.texi"'`.  If you want them to type `--incl` to define suffixes to include, then you might as well have them type `--include`.  Sorry, I'm failing to see your issue.

Comment: Definitely simpler.  I actually have got a function that captures text within a begin and end region (line number p to line number q) or using either `head` or`tail` to capture from beginning or end.  Was thinking of incorporating the pattern search to it as well.  At least that wan the original motivation.

Comment: Yes, can get them to type `include`.  It was just for things to be rapid in typing and running the command.

Comment: @Pietru Maybe you need to talk to your users before deciding what they need?

Comment: The plan was to have completion for a specific utility on the terminal.  E.g.  `indus-<tab>` followed by `indus-list -h` where the help is not too extensive as doing `info grep`.  Constrain things a little bit.  I do not have to worry so much with relatively experienced users.

Comment: @Pietru Now you're talking about a separate script and about completion. I'm noticing that this is not mentioned _at all_ in your question, and I'm not sure how it's relevant to the question about passing two separate lists of filename suffixes to a _shell function_.

Comment: I am only discussing  passing two separate lists of filename suffixes, rather than the other things.  But as some asked, I explained.  Was asked about having the users simply use grep,

Comment: @Kusalananda You mentioned handling any type of filename.  What the implementation idea exactly?

Comment: @Pietru See my latest variant at the end of my answer now.  I'd still argue that you question is lacking a lot of details that I've had to work around in the various incarnations of my code in my answer.  You may want to update the question with what you are expecting.  A call signature fro the function would be nice, i.e. how you expect the function to be called.

Comment: How would you use `call_grep` for `,v`, etc ?

Comment: @Pietru That last variation of the function? `call_grep -e ,v` followed by whatever other options. If you really want to use brace expansions, `call_grep -e{",v",.othersuffix}` etc.

Comment: There is not a particular need for braces as long as things are well defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the list of extensions in the form `el,htm`, you might be *tempted* to do something like this to use brace expansion:

```
eval 'echo grep -hir --exclude=*.{'"$excl"'} "$@"'
```

but apart from the usual caveats with `eval`, like the fact that an unquoted semicolon in `$excl` would mess up the syntax by terminating the `grep` command, it also wouldn't work if `$excl` contained only one extension, or none at all, since `{foo}` and `{}` are *not* processed as brace expansions. So, let's forget about the brace expansion.

---

We're really going to end up building the list of arguments in an array, like in Kusalananda's answer above, and in [Conditionally pass params to a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446847/170373)

Keeping with the comma as separator, the simple way to split on the comma is with `read -a`. It produces an array and we need another to build the list of options in.

```
excl="el,htm"
IFS=, read -r -a exts <<< "$excl"
opts=()
for ext in "${exts[@]}"; do 
     opts+=(--exclude="*.$ext")
done
grep -hir "${opts[@]}" "$@"
```

As you noticed in comments, extensions like RCS's `,v` would be a problem here, and so would anything else that doesn't start with a dot. If you still want to give the extensions as one string, you could switch to accepting e.g. a colon, semicolon or a space as the delimiter, and require to user to enter the dot explicitly if they want it, so e.g. with `:` as the delimiter:

```
excl=".html:,v"
IFS=: read -r -a exts <<< "$excl"
opts=()
for ext in "${exts[@]}"; do 
     opts+=(--exclude="*$ext")
done
grep -hir "${opts[@]}" "$@"
```

Of course, what ever character you choose to use as separator, can't be part of an extension, but semicolons and colons are probably rarer still than commas.