# operating on a list when some lines contain spaces

Tags: text-processing

I'm trying to build a list of directories to exclude from a find command.  Unfortunately sone of the directories have spaces in them.  For example, suppose I have a list `myList` of three directories, the second of which is called "b c"

```
/bin/bash
myList="a \\
        b c \\
        d"
```

I'm unable to convince 'bash` not to break up the second line into two individual tokens.

for example, this code

```
dirList=
stringArray=($myList)
for i in "${stringArray[@]}" ; do
    dirList="$dirList -name $i -prune -o"
    echo "$dirList"
    echo " "
done
```

returns this:

```
-name a -prune -o

 -name a -prune -o -name b -prune -o

 -name a -prune -o -name b -prune -o -name c -prune -o

 -name a -prune -o -name b -prune -o -name c -prune -o -name d -prune -o
```

But I want it to return

```
-name a -prune -o

 -name a -prune -o -name b c -prune -o

 -name a -prune -o -name b c -prune -o -name d -prune -o
```

The obvious way to deal with the space is to define the second line as `"b c"`  But then I have nested double quotes.   I've tried (I believe) all of the suggestions on the web about dealing with nested quotes, but none are working for m. Could somebody please advise how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply define your list as an array from the very beginning, rather than as a string that you then parse into an array? That way you could create an array of strings, bounded by doublequotes, able to handle spaces in a non-tokenized fashion?

Frex:

```
#!/bin/bash
myList=("a" "b c" "d")
dirList=
stringArray=$myList
for i in "${stringArray[@]}" ; do
    dirList="$dirList -name $i -prune -o"
    echo "$dirList"
    echo " "
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the string `-name a -prune -o name b c -prune ...` either, since what actually goes to the command you run is not a single string, but multiple strings. It's just that when you write `foo bar "a b"`, the shell interprets the quotes and splits the command line on unquoted whitespace, giving you the three strings `foo`, `bar` and `a b`. Similarly, what you want to eventually go to `find` is the arguments `-o`, `-name`, `a b`, `-prune` etc. If you have the string `-o -name a b -prune`, it's hard to make it so that the string is split on the other spaces, but *isn't* split between the `a` and the `b`.

First you need some way to read the newline-separated list of names, without breaking the individual lines. Since you mentioned Bash, there's the `mapfile` (`readarray`) command for that. Let's assume for now that you have that list of names in another file. Then,

```
readarray -t names < listfile
```

would fill the array `names` with the contents of the file, one entry per line.

Note that in your question, the string in `myList` also contains backslashes and spaces in front of the second and third directories, which you'd probably want to clean up if you store the list like that. Or you could just store the list as an array directly, like in [@James S.'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665788/170373).

---

Then, the second issue is building the list of arguments to `find`. There, you also need an array to keep the arguments intact and separate. So,

```
args=()
for n in "${names[@]}"; do
    args+=(-name "$n" -prune -o)
done
```

would fill the array `args` with arguments. You'd then use it as

```
find ... "${args[@]}"
```

---

Also, you don't need to repeat the `-prune`, you can wrap the whole thing in parenthesis and just have `-prune` once on the outside, e.g. on the command line, you'd use `... "(" -name this -o -name that ")" -prune ...` and you could fill the array something like this

```
args=("(")
for n in "${names[@]}"; do
    args+=(-name "$n" -o)
done
unset "args[${#args[@]} - 1]"  # remove the last -o
args+=( ")" -prune )
```

See:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable/444949#444949)
- [Conditionally pass params to a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446847/conditionally-pass-params-to-a-script/446848#446848)
- [BashFAQ 050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [special variable IFS](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ifs-shell-variable)

```
 #!/bin/bash
OFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

myList="a \\
        b c \\
        d"

dirList=
stringArray=($myList)
for i in "${stringArray[@]}" ; do
    dirList="$dirList -name $i -prune -o"
    echo "$dirList"
    echo " "
done
IFS=$OFS
```

This is the given output:

```
 -name a \ -prune -o
 
 -name a \ -prune -o -name         b c \ -prune -o
 
 -name a \ -prune -o -name         b c \ -prune -o -name         d -prune -o
```