# How to integrate multiple inline `if` variable checks into `configure` flag selection

Tags: variable, configure

I'm compiling Nginx from source on Debian 12 in Bash. I'd like to select the TLS vendor (e.g. LibreSSL, OpenSSL) via a preflight variable (`$nginx_tls_vendor`). An example `configure` command without the variable stuff looks like this:

```
./configure \
--with-foo \
[…]
--with-openssl=/src/vendor/library-1.2.3 \
--with-openssl-opt="baz" \
[…]
--with-bar \
```

The values of the `--with-openssl` and `--with-openssl-opt` flags depend on `$nginx_tls_vendor`. Broadly like this for each vendor:

```
if [ "$nginx_tls_vendor" = "libressl" ] \
; then \
--with-openssl=/src/libressl/libressl-1.2.3 \
--with-openssl-opt="baz-libressl etc" \
; fi
```

```
if [ "$nginx_tls_vendor" = "openssl" ] \
; then \
--with-openssl=/src/openssl/openssl-3.2.1 \
--with-openssl-opt="baz-openssl etc" \
; fi
```

I haven't yet figured out how to use one or more `if` checks inline within a command. I am reasonably comfortable with an `if` wrapper around an entire command, but this doesn't apply here. I would like to use two inline `if` checks to find the TLS vendor and apply the relevant flags.

I've tried various things that might work but they end up breaking my download-and-compile script.

I would be grateful for some guidance and / or further reading so I can integrate two consecutive `if` checks around the two `--with-openssl` and `--with-openssl-opt` flags.

Thank you.

Comment: Why all the `\ `in the `if` line there? That makes it really hard to read. You can write `if [ condition ]; then` and just start a new line, or `if [ condition ]` (without the `;`, that isn't needed if you add a newline) and have the `then` in a new line, and you don't need `then \ `, you can just move straight on to the next line. None of this is related to your question, just pointing it out FYI.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for your comment and guidance on the punctuation. I am (overly) verbose as I have all my build scripts as Markdown files in a repository and I copy / paste into a terminal window. The slashes help me to understand as I'm learning, and it's more granular on the change control side of things so I can see exactly what part(s) I've updated in my commit history. The Nginx `configure` flag stuff is split over ~60 lines in my IDE, so I can add / remove stuff in testing with a full history of what I've done.

Comment: OK. But my pint was that you can still split over many lines, the slashes are not needed. But they are not wrong, so if you really prefer it, that's your call.

Answer (score 4):

There are some ways to put conditionals inline with the command, but really, it's probably best to just build the list of arguments in an array (at least the varying ones) and then use the array when running the program. As long as you're using Bash anyway, since arrays aren't a standard feature. (See links below for alternative solutions.)

If you're just testing a single variable against a set of values, the `case` stament might be nicer than an `if`. (Not that there's anything wrong with `if`, either.)

The main parts are the `args+=(foo)` assignment to append to the array, and the array expansion `"${args[@]}"`.

Something like this:

```
args=()
case "$nginx_tls_vendor" in
    libressl) 
        args+=(
        --with-openssl=/src/libressl/libressl-1.2.3
        --with-openssl-opt="baz-libressl etc"
        );;
    openssl) 
        args+=(
        --with-openssl=/src/openssl/openssl-3.2.1
        --with-openssl-opt="baz-openssl etc"
        );;
    *) 
        echo >&2 "error: invalid value of 'nginx_tls_vendor'"
        exit 1;;
esac

./configure --with-foo "${args[@]}" --with-bar
```

Or, you could even apply associative arrays (again in Bash):

```
declare -A openssl_libs=(
    [libressl]=/src/libressl/libressl-1.2.3
    [openssl]=/src/openssl/openssl-3.2.1
)
declare -A openssl_opts=(
    [libressl]="baz-libressl etc"
    [openssl]="baz-openssl etc"
)

./configure \
  --with-foo \
  --with-openssl="${openssl_libs[$nginx_tls_vendor]}" \
  --with-openssl-opt="${openssl_opts[$nginx_tls_vendor]}" \
  --with-bar \

#end
```

(Though watch for invalid values of `$nginx_tls_vendor` there.)

See also:

- [Conditionally pass params to a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446847/170373)
- [Using shell variables for command options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/459367/170373)
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

<sub>(While you could technically embed `if` staments within a command substitution directly in the argument list of `configure`, that would be awkward wrt. quoting and word splitting, slightly inefficient and probably somewhat difficult to read, too. Wouldn't suggest doing that.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much - this looks like a much cleaner & sensible approach.